# Make Spotlight to index WebDAV network drive?

Tags: finder, network, spotlight, smb, webdav

I have a network drive, which I mount to Finder using WebDAV protocol. Even though it works with no problems, Spotlight can't index it.
However, when I mount this disk using SMB3, it does get indexed.
Why is that? Does it mean that Spotlight can't index WebDAV connected network drives?
This is what I get in Terminal when trying to turn indexing on when the disk is connected using WebDAV:

```
user@MacBook-Pro ~ % mdutil -s /Volumes/storage.WebDAVdrive.tw    
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/storage.WebDAVdrive.tw:
    Indexing disabled.
user@MacBook-Pro ~ % mdutil -i on /Volumes/storage.WebDAVdrive.tw
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/storage.WebDAVdrive.tw:
    Indexing disabled.
user@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: fo real man? Like seriously no one not gonna ansa me?